# Accessing property on DisplayClass object at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, anonymous-function, anonymous-types

**Environment:** VS2017, C# 7.0 targeting .NET Core 2.1.

I'm trying to write a fake/mock class to use for unit testing, and I'm having difficulties accessing a property on a `DisplayClass` object, which I understand  is [a closure class from an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16401860/606576).

My code looks like this:

```cs
namespace MyCompany.Application.Web.Test.Fakes
{
    public class FakeElasticClient : IElasticClient
    {
        public FakeElasticClient() { }

        public Task<ISearchResponse<T>> SearchAsync<T>(Func<SearchDescriptor<T>, ISearchRequest> selector = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class
        {
            var methodName = selector.Method.Name;
            dynamic tgt = selector.Target;
            object id = tgt?.GetType().GetProperty("id")?.GetValue(tgt, null);
            int? total;
            if (methodName.Contains("Quux"))
            {
                total = CountSomething((Guid)id);
            }
            else
            {
                total = CountSomethingElse((Guid)id);
            }

            return Task.Run(() => new FakeSearchResponse<T>(total ?? 0) as ISearchResponse<T>);
        }

        // … below here follows a couple thousand other methods
```

Casting `id` to `Guid` throws a `NullReferenceException`, even though the Visual Studio debugger shows the `tgt` object has an `id` property:

[image: Visual Studio debugger]

Comments:

- I have stolen the `object id = …` line from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1203538/606576).
- `tgt.GetType()` returns `MyCompany.Application.Domain.Repository.Implementations.BusinessEntityRepository.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`
- `tgt.GetType().GetProperties()` returns an empty `PropertyInfo` array.
- Inspired by [this blog post](https://juristr.com/blog/2013/08/object-does-not-contain-definition/) I added an `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyCompany.Application.Web.Test")]` attribute to both the `MyCompany.Application.Domain.Repository.Implementations.BusinessEntityRepository` and the `MyCompany.Application.Web.Controllers` class, which as far as I can tell are the only two classes involved in the call chain. Didn't make any difference.
- I tried futzing around with `IgnoresAccessChecksTo` [as described here](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/10/no-internalvisibleto-no-problem-bypassing-c-visibility-rules-with-roslyn/), but couldn't make anything compile.

How do I retrieve the value for `id`?

Comment: The compiler generates closure types with fields rather than properties, so `id` would be a field; try `tgt.GetType().GetFields()`. That said, I think you're taking unit testing too far if you have to deal with the compiler's implementation details.

Comment: It's actually a rather simple unit test, the problem is that the value I need to access here is inside an anonymous function passed to the method. In any case you are perfectly correct and it works when I change the line to `object id = tgt?.GetType().GetField("id")?.GetValue(tgt);`. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it correct. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler generates closure types with fields rather than properties, so `id` is a field.  Use `tgt.GetType().GetFields()` instead.

Comment: TIL the difference between Fields and Properties. Thank you!